# curl json with cookie returns "‹ŠŽÿÿ)»L"

Tags: php, json, curl, cookies

i am trying to get the content of this json: http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=DE&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Chroma%20Case

This is my code:

```
$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=DE&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Chroma%20Case";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'steamLogin = 76561198075419487%7C%7C3F1A776553C4BE1D0F6DA83059052E79DB7EB3C7');

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json_string = json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

When printing out `$json_string` it results in nothing, `$output` results in "‹ŠŽÿÿ)»L". I would like to grab the actual content on the website, the `steamLogin`-Cookie is needed for that. The cookie that's stored in my browser at the moment is the one I hardcoded in the source.

If you need any more info, feel free to ask.

Comment: try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");` (to handle the response being gzipped) - The space around `=` in the cookie looks wrong.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks! That really made it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");` made it :)